# Viber API documentation problem with conversation_started event

Tags: viber

Official Viber API docs doesn't really help on this event, only emphasising that send_message shouldn't be endpoint when triggered. Does anyone know how to code this event for chatbot welcome message in PHP? I covered whole web and found nothing.

Answer (score 1):

For `welcome_message` you should just echo `json_welcome_message` in `'conversation_started'` handler section, don't send it to `send_message` endpoint.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing, and I'm not seeing the result I want
    `if ($input['event'] == 'conversation_started') {`
      `$data['sender']['name'] = "EIR";`
      `$data['type'] = "text";`
      `$data['text'] = "welcome";`
      `echo json_encode($data);`
   ` }`

what I'm I doing wrong? 

It's also difficult to test, since the welcome message is sent once per user... Or is there a way to send it many times to the same user?

Thanks!

Comment: I recommend you check webhook, and add logging  for income and outcome `json_message` to be sure you get `'conversation_started'` event and test you solution.

Comment: No, you can delete bot and `conversation_started` event occur again.